# Where to find timeline and other info for GLIBCXX

Tags: gcc, c++14

Any Google search I've tried gives me information on GLIBC (not C++) library, GCC (the compiler), or an occasional hit involving the token `GLIBCXX` without any other relevance.  I've tried searching for things like `feature` and `roadmap` which have returned similar information for the compiler syntax.  But I'm looking for information on the *library*.

The Mac's development system appears to use Clang with GLIBCXX version 4.2.1 (that version at least on the system I looked at).  I've seen from the Clang roadmap that C++11/14 support is pretty much a done deal.  So I was surprised that it objected to `using namespace std::string_literals;`, since user-defined literals seem to be supported by Clang and `"blah"s` is a one-line bit of syntactic sugar to stick in the header.

Is there a roadmap or other documentation showing which C++11/14 **standard library** features are available, not available, not usable, coming soon, never coming, etc?

Any idea why *such* low-hanging fruit would not have been in there?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html for libstdc++; http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1y_status.html for libc++. Presumably you're asking about the former, but I honestly can't tell. In any case, asking where to find off-site resources is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks @ildjarn that was exactly what I was looking for.  I beleive the first one is for the library whose headers claim to be part of GLIBCXX. But the point is that the features are keyed to the *dialect* selection of the language. The std::string_literals only are exposed if you ask for c++14 (or later).

Answer (score 0):

to clarify, even though the namespace is `GLIBCXX`, it's not actually relevant to glibc at all.  this is entirely contained under the gcc project.

the reason Apple pinned to gcc-4.2 is because later versions switched to GPL-3.  they didn't want to deal with that because they want to retain 100% control over the OS (and your hardware), so they never upgraded.

if you want to know more about the GNU libstdc++, then check out its homepage: https://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/

that has all the details you're looking for afaict.

Comment: The first para of my question states that I don't want the glibc info, so what is the meaning of your first para?  Your second para on not using gcc is relavent how...? I know I'm using Clang.

Comment: my point is that glibc is irrelevant to your question.  it's like saying "i'm interested in buying a car, but i don't want information about motorcycles".  if you aren't interested in motorcycles, then why did you mention it at all ?  by saying "glibc", it implies you think it's relevant.  same goes for gcc: Apple is using libstdc++ from the gcc project (the 4.2 release series).  the fact you're using clang is irrelevant -- the llvm project for the longest time didn't have a C++ runtime library, so everyone still uses gcc's libstdc++.

Comment: Why mention glibc: by pointing out what I keep turning up *instead*, I show that I researched the question before asking, and prevent answerers from making the same mistake. It does not imply that I think it's relevant when I complain that I got results for something other than what I really was looking for.  I thought my first sentence in the OP was pretty clear.